# Which variable does 'synthetic' set in Varnish 4?

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl, varnish-4

In vcl_synth I am trying to craft modified error pages; I may move this to vcl_backend_error, but that is moot as the problem remains the same. I am using CentOS 7, so only have access to 4.0, not 4.1. This is important as std.file_exists only exists in >= 4.1. It is unacceptable to use packages from untrusted, untested, sources that break forwards/backwards compatibility.

To handle issues where the 503.html file may not exist I would like to test the synthetic output, and if null/empty generate a fallback error page. For debugging I'm throwing all output to syslog; this will not persist to production, in its current form.

Sample:

```
sub vcl_synth {
    if (resp.status == 503) {
        set resp.http.Content-Type = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
        synthetic(std.fileread("/var/www/vhost/" + req.http.host + "/error/503.html"));
        std.syslog(3, "resp.http.body: " + resp.http.body);
        return (deliver);
    }
}
```

With the above I clearly see that resp.http.body is empty, but the page is returned and renders in my browser. So, if it does, which variable does synthetic set? And, can it be tested?

```
# journalctl -f
...
Sep 08 02:17:17 REDACTED_HOSTNAME varnishd[32498]: resp.http.body:
```

pls halp

Answer (score 1):

Execution of `synthetic(...)` during `vcl_synth` does not populate `resp.http.body`. That's just a random header name. One possible approach would be to populate a 'temporary variable' with the response body:

```
sub vcl_synth {
    if (resp.status == 503) {
        set resp.http.Content-Type = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
        set req.http.X-Synth-Body = std.fileread("/var/www/vhost/" + req.http.host + "/error/503.html");
        synthetic(req.http.X-Synth-Body);
        std.syslog(3, "req.http.X-Synth-Body: " + req.http.X-Synth-Body);
        return (deliver);
    }
}
```

Comment: You've inspired me. Set the fileread as a variable and then test the variable to handle the null case. When I have some working code I'll update my original post; muchas gracias señor :)

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the:

> It is unacceptable to use packages from untrusted, untested, sources
>   that break forwards/backwards compatibility.

Varnish has a [dedicated repository for 4.1](https://packagecloud.io/varnishcache/varnish41/install#manual).

Those packages are signed, specific to 4.1 branch only and should not break forward/backward compatibility.

Plus, since you're using their software you essentially already trust them. Moreover, there are recent security updates that might make it faster to their repository and not the EPEL, etc.

And Varnish 4.0 is officially EOL.

Comment: Thank you, that's definitely the best solution going forward, but such changes require testing and validation; thankfully I think I have a method to fix my issue for the short term. Author repositories are definitely the way to go, provided your platform is fully supported; third party repos, generally not so much.. :)